# WPF - Draw tilted grid between two points

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-positioning

I'm writing a graph (nodes and links) designing program where the main designer allows users to shift nodes (represented as ellipses) about and to add links between the node.

The problem now is that I would like to add labels to the links. The labels should be parallel to the links, i.e. the labels should not be horizontal if the links are diagonal. These links are typically just on top or below the link line.

I'm now using the a Grid instead of just a Line for the View part of the link to contain the labels and the line. The midpoints of both ends of the grid should lie exactly at the position of the two attached nodes.

However, unlike the Line control, the Grid control does not have X1 Y1 X2 Y2 properties to bind its two "endpoints" to. Since the Line control is neither a ContentControl, I am unable to embed a Grid in a Line as well.

Are there any possible solutions to this?